# Convert hyperlinks to buttons

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets, I have a column of active hyperlinks. When you hover over one of them, a tool tip appears that contains an "open link" icon that you can click on to open the URL in a new tab.

In each cell, instead of showing the entire URL, I'd like to replace that text with a "view" button that can be clicked immediately (without having to wait for that hover-delayed tool-tip, which requires a brief delay and additional mouse-movements before you can click to open the URL).

Keep in mind, that each URL is different (in this column) and I'm looking for a solution where I can highlight all of them and convert each to a button labeled "view" that opens its respective url in a new browser-tab.

Is this feature available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. That is not how Google chose to implement links across Sheets, Docs, etc. In each case, but especially when the link text differs from the url, for User Experience reasons they chose to make the reader see the "address snippet popup", complete with the icon indicating it will take them to a new page. Google is a hulking giant, but they do say they welcome feedback—if you choose, you can go to your file, and choose Report a Problem from the Help menu.

Achieving this exact behavior, if you truly need it, would entail extending Sheets' inbuilt feature set. I have no specific recommendations, but if it is a requirement for you, perhaps research into whether this could be achieved with a third-party Sheets add-on or by programming your own Apps Script, since there is no native option.